# ssh login after changed IP

Tags: ssh, ip

I have server running Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (`GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab078.28 i686`)

Had no problem logging in to the server via ssh until my Internet Provider changed my IP. Now, the server keeps adding my IP to `/etc/hosts.deny` blacklist. Even when I delete it by hand and gives me `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`.

As I login with root (not secure, I know...) I removed my pub key from `/root/.ssh/known_hosts`, but it didn't help, so clearly there are other security mechanisms which I'm not aware of.

Could somebody please give me some directions where I should look for the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at /etc/hosts.allow, your old IP address should be listed there, modify the line with your new IP:

sshd: new.ip.add.ress

This security mechanism is called TCP Wrappers.

Comment: Although old IP was not listed in hosts.allow adding the new one prevents system from adding my IP to blacklist. Thanks!